# Rowspan substituída por outro atributo

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber se a propriedade "rowspan" do css foi substituída por outra equivalente e qual seria essa nova propriedade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiramente, talvez vc não esteja achando a referencia de `rowspan` no CSS pq **`rowspan` não é uma propriedade CSS**, ele na verdade, assim como o `colspan`, **`rowspan` é um atributo HTML!**

E sim tanto `colspan` quanto `rowspan`estão "vivos"! E são aceitos em 100% dos browsers como vc pode consultar nessa documentação do Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Essas propriedades são atributos globais da `TD` e `TH` e são definidos no HTML, direto na tag, não no CSS. Por exemplo **isso não existe** `th, td { colspan: 3 }`

Aqui tem um exemplo de aplicação. Repare que nem CSS tem nesse código, e `colspan` e `rowspan`são usados direto na tag HTML, como seria um `name` ou `title`, ou qq outro [atributo global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) do HTML

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>normal</th>
      <th colspan="2">colspan="2"</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10000</td>
      <th rowspan="3">rowspan="3"</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>20000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>30000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```