# Tabela HTML Complexa com bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, table

Como fazer tabelas mais complexas em html e utilizar o bootstrap?
pesquisei pela web a fora, mas não consegui compreender muito bem.
como eu posso criar essa tabela em HTML, e usar bootstrap.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poria me dar pelo menos um norte, para q eu possa criar essa tabela em HTML, e usar as estilizações do bootstrap

Comment: Não vai achar lugar melhor que a documentação oficial: https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/content/tables/

Comment: o meu problema maior, não é nem com a estilização, meu problema, maior é como criar essa tabela em html!, nunca fiz uma tabela assim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui mesmo na documentação tem descrito isso https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/#bordered-table na verdade vc tem que usar `colspan` ou `rowspan` dependendo de como quer expandir as células da tabela, e isso não tem nada a ver com o Bootstrap em si...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qui tem um exemplo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />

</head>

<body>

   
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                        <th scope="col" colspan="3" class="text-center">Heading</th>
                        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                        <td>Cell</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pois é, o meu problema maior, é na estruturação do html, para montar essa table

Comment: @RafaelPassos ta ai o exemplo, vc pode começar a sua a partir dele. E estudo sobre colspan e rowspan. Isso vai te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400703/rowspan-substitu%c3%adda-por-outro-atributo/400715#400715